# License plate Detection from car camera

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I am using Python and Opencv. I am doing a project to recognize the license plate from a car camera.

I have tried to use `Canny()`, but I still cant recognize the plate.

Here is the frame I captured.
[image]

1)

First, I convert the image into **gray-scale**, increase the **contract of color** and finally convert it into "**edged image**"

```
img = cv2.imread("plate.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.equalizeHist(gray)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 200, 255)
```

Here is the result that what I get:
[image]

2)

Afterwards, I try to find a **rectangle contour** as following, I tried to filter out the **irrelevant rectangle** by area and length and **irregular polygon** by `convexHull()`:

```
(cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts=sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:10]

# loop over our contours
plate_candidates = []
    for c in cnts:
        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
        area = cv2.contourArea(approx)
        if len(approx) == 4 and area <=1000 and area >=500 and self._length_checking(approx):
            hull = cv2.convexHull(approx,returnPoints = True)
            if len(hull) ==4:
                plate_candidates.append(approx)
                cv2.drawContours(show, [approx], -1, (0,255,0), 3)
```

But still, I cannot recognize the plate. I am looking for help how can I detect the license plate. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use minimal bounding rectangle of the convex hull to calculate the "rectangleness" of your candidate contours (in the latest version of openCV you can use `cv2.boxPoints` to calculate `rectPoints`):

```
def rectangleness(hull):
    rect = cv2.boundingRect(hull)
    rectPoints = np.array([[rect[0], rect[1]], 
                           [rect[0] + rect[2], rect[1]],
                           [rect[0] + rect[2], rect[1] + rect[3]],
                           [rect[0], rect[1] + rect[3]]])
    intersection_area = cv2.intersectConvexConvex(np.array(rectPoints), hull)[0] 
    rect_area = cv2.contourArea(rectPoints)
    rectangleness = intersection_area/rect_area
    return rectangleness
```

However in your case this is actually overkill, it's enough to use the area of the polygon — either of the polygons within your area cutoff (the first two contours in `cnts`) could be used to obtain the bounding rectangle surrounding the licence plate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean that the constraints that I used are too strict? By using the `area` and `rectangleness` is good enough to detect the rectangle?

Comment: in your case you don't even need rectangleness, you can just use area

Comment: I did use this method before, however, sometimes I will detect some non-quadrilateral shape. In order to filter out these non-quadrilateral or irregular shape, I use the `len(hull)==4` to determine

Comment: For most of the polygon, `rectangleness` still returns 1. I have asked another question about finding rectangle. See if you can help. Thanks! [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39071418/6343552)

Comment: yeah that's because they mostly are rectangles ;)